# Always return a value from a snippet of javascript

Tags: javascript

The problem:  taking an arbitrary string of javascript code and consistently returning a value from it and assigning it to a variable.  I need to build up a string of javascript that, when evaled, will consistently set a variable to whatever the return value of the original arbitrary string of javascript would return.  Example, this string of javascript:

```
if(typeof(something) !== "undefined"){
  hello()
}
```

This is how I'm trying to do it now (and yes, I know the above snippet would not return anything)

```
var result = (function(){
  if(typeof(something) !== "undefined"){
     hello()
   }
}.call(this)
```

And thus result is undefined.  How, in the above case and in all (or most) others, can I get a result that is not undefined?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you are trying to do this? If "an arbitrary string of javascript code" doesn't return something (like your first example) then what possible defined value could you expect? Where would the value come from?

Answer (score 1):

If you never expect a *falsy* value (`''`, `0`, `false`, `undefined` or `null`) from your function, this will work.

```
var result = function(){
  if(typeof something  !== "undefined"){
     hello()
   }
}.call(this) || 'default_value';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pM2Y9/).